# Would Parse javascript SDK work with NativeScript?

Tags: parse-platform, nativescript

I'm planning to build an app using NativeScript for the front end and Parse for the backend.  Has anyone tried and gone down this path?  I would love to hear your experience before I invested too much time and found out they don't work nicely together.

From what I've learned the last few days, there's no DOM for NativeScript.  Does Parse Javascript SDK work similarly with the assumption that there's no DOM?

Comment: If the SDK uses any DOM then you won't be able to use it with {N}, you would need to work with the native SDKs, but since Parse is shutting down you probably should look into another service.

Comment: Did you have a go and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a scan around online and I can't find much information on whether their compatible. I guess the only way to find out is to give it a go. I'd be interested in the result though.